# Call iterator method from within a nested class

Tags: java, methods, iterator, nested

Here is a nested class within one of my classes. How can I call the `remove` method from a new method called `public Cards dealOut()` ? Does it have to be within the nested class or is there a way of doing it outside of it?

```
    public class D_iterator <Cards> implements Iterator <Cards> {
    int pos = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (pos < deckOfCards.size()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;           
    }

    @Override
    public Cards next() {
        return (Cards) deckOfCards.get(pos+1);
    }


    @Override
    public void remove (){
        deckOfCards.remove(pos);

    } 

}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know if you can call a method in the class this is nested in?

Comment: This iterator doesn't work because you don't advance `pos` when you call `next()` (or otherwise). Do you mean `deckOfCards.get(pos++);`?

Comment: Yes this is nested within a class. I want to call the remove method in a separate method which still remains in the overall class but not within this nested class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The usual paradigm is to have the class that contains `D_iterator` implement `Iterable<Cards>`, which means it will have an `iterator()` method that returns an instance of `D_iterator`.

Users of that outer class will call `iterator()` to obtain the Iterator and invoke its methods.

P.S. you should fix your `next()` method, since you never increment `pos`. It will always return `deckOfCards.get(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The inner `remove()` method is not static (and can't be for various reasons) so you need an object reference in order to call it. You should move the "removing logic" to the outer class and call that from within the iterator.